# PHP preg_match with file_get_contents

Tags: php, expression, preg-match, file-get-contents

I have a text on a page and I want to get if to other page by using 
`preg_match` and `file_get_content` functions

the text on `page1.php` is

```
return(["h","t","t","p",":","\/","\/","1","7",".","2","4","8",".","1","7","4",".","3","8",":","8","0","8","1","\/"])
```

i want to get the text from `page1.php` to `page2.php` like this

The IP is : http://17.248.174.38:8081/

the IP is automatically now is 17.248.174.38:8081, after refresh can became 133.213.171.33:8081 so it's generated from page1

I tried this code but it not working

```
   <?php
    $url = "http://localhost/page1.php";
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/(http?\:\/\/[^\']*\.8081*)/', $contents, $result);
    $link = urldecode($result[0]);
    $echo "The IP is :" $link;
    ?>
```

any help please, I'm just beginner in php

the IP 17.248.174.38 can be changed on any time a refresh the page

thanks

Comment: the IP 17.248.174.38:8081 can be changed autmaticaly to any other ip

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

in page2.php use this

```
<?php
$url = "page1.php"; // use file location in refrence of the current file. 
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/return\(\[\"h\",\"t\",.+\]\)/i', $contents, $result);
$result = json_decode(trim(str_replace("return","",$result[0]),"()"));
$link = urldecode($result);
$echo "The IP is :" $link;
?>
```

`json_decode()` is used to decode and parse the response (which is a JSON array), then `implode()` joins all the array elements into a single string, so it can be passed into `preg_match()`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks but on the page1.php i have every refesh of the page new IP so first time can be return(["h","t","t","p",":","/","/","1","7",".","2","4","8",".","1","7","4",".","3","8",":","8","0","8","1","/"]) ,     second refresh can be return(["h","t","t","p",":","/","/","1","4",".","2","1","8",".","1","7","6",".","3","8",":","8","0","8","1","/"])

Comment: so what i want exactly is to get what is on the return([from this to this]) and put it on preg_match

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns `return(["h","t","t","p",":","/","/","1","7",".","2","4","8",‌​".","1","7","4",".",‌​"3","8",":","8","0",‌​"8","1","/"])` ??

Comment: on page1.php there is lot of text an code , but i want only get what is on return value , on this example return(["h","t","t","p",":","/","/","1","7",".","2","4","8",".","1","7","4",".","3","8",":","8","0","8","1","/"])   i want to get what is on the return and show it on the page2.php correctryl like http://17.248.174.38:8081/

Comment: Updated the answer